# Http request with header in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

Im currently trying to get a JSON response back from the backend however when i execute the GET-request I get the the following errors(see first image). *Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401*

[image: error screenshot]

However Im certain that the backend is running fine and the url and header(token) are correct, because postman does return the wanted result(see second image).

[image]

this is my code I used httpclient and httpclientmodule(in appmodule.ts). I also added a chrome plugin(allow-control-allow-origin), which solved the previous *allow access-control-allow-origin* error. So I personally think there is something wrong with either my header or some conflict with the http request.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-process-category',
  templateUrl: './process-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./process-category.component.css']
})
export class ProcessCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8084/LOGwearServer/Database/main/abstract?typeOne=PROCESSCATEGORIES&typeTwo=PROCESSCATEGORIES',
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('token', '994847565472878394039283578235')
      })
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: I got the same error may I ask if this problem was already sorted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add word **Bearer** while sending the token for example try passing like this

```
headers: new HttpHeaders().set('token', 'Bearer 994847565472878394039283578235')
```

I had the same issue and I fixed it by passing the word.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However adding the 'Bearer' keyword dind't resolve the issue.